# Filter transactions based on products purchased

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

In Google Analytics, I gather e-commerce data, allowing me to track purchases. There is a specific analysis, however, which I cannot imagine how to set up. I need to verify how big a percentage of a revenue is generated by transactions which include product X but not products Y and Z. I have attempted to set this up in a custom report, but cannot figure out exactly which combination of dimensions, metrics and filters to use.

Comment: In your Product Performance report, you can create an advanced filter (eg. using Regex) to filter by your products. You can filter either product names or SKUs. I would think SKUs would be easier, as it's easier to match a pattern to them with Regex.

Comment: Hi nyuen
I have been trying to alter the Product Performance report. However it looks to as if I cannot apply a filter on product level, and report aggregated numbers on transaction level.

Comment: I have been trying to alter the Product Performance report, even before I wrote my original post. However it looks to as if I cannot apply a filter on product level, and report aggregated numbers on transaction level. If I choose Product Revenue as metric, Month as dimension, and add filter on Product including regex (X) and excluding (Y) and (Z) I don't get any figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're still wondering;

If you make a segment with "Product = X" and then go to the Transaction report you'll see the amount of transactions with only that product.

Took me a while to figure out as well.